# Isolation-mode (regfree) COM references defined twice (build error MSB3180)

Tags: com, reference, regfreecom

I have several C# projects in one solution which reference some isolation-mode (regfree) COM DLLs. Some projects reference the same DLL, and when I build, I get `error [MSB3180][1]: COM component 'SomeDll.dll' is defined in both 'Native.SomeProject.manifest' and 'Native.SomeOtherProject.manifest'"`.

The projects must reference the same COM DLL, since they both use it, and both are completely independent of one another. It gets more complicated since I want to support non-isolation mode for Debug builds.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

All those projects could reference a new DLL that acts as a wrapper to the singular DLL that references the Reg-Free COM.